# Gеtting an error while choosing random file from directory

Tags: python, file, random

I am trying to choose a random .PNG file from directory - there are 5 PNG files (1,2,3,4,5/png)

Python version is 3.8.2

Here is my code:

```
import os
import random

file_path = random.choice(os.listdir(r"C:/Users/katherine/Desktop/testphotos"))
client.users_setPhoto(image=file_path)
```

But I get an error something about "there is no such file"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):     
File "C:/Users/katherine/Desktop/testcode/main.py", line 14, in <module>
        client.users_setPhoto(image=file_path)     
File "C:\Users\katherine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slack\web\client.py", line 1638, in users_setPhoto
        return self.api_call("users.setPhoto", files={"image": image}, data=kwargs)     
File "C:\Users\katherine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slack\web\base_client.py", line 171, in api_call
        return self._event_loop.run_until_complete(future)     
File "C:\Users\katherine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
        return future.result()     
File "C:\Users\katherine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\slack\web\base_client.py", line 207, in _send

f = open(v.encode("ascii", "ignore"), "rb")  

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'3.png'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `os.listdir` returns a list with only filenames. ie, not abs path. You can create the full path with `os.path.join("C:/Users/katherine/Desktop/testphotos", file_path )
` before passing into `users_setPhoto` method.

Answer (score 1):

Only the **filename** is returned from `os.listdir()`, whereas your `users_setPhoto()` call will require the full path.

Try using `os.path.join()` to join the returned filename with the root path.

For example ...

```
path = 'C:/Users/katherine/Desktop/testphotos'
file_path = os.path.join(path, random.choice(os.listdir(path)))
client.users_setPhoto(image=file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

[@S3DEV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60652821/6162307)'s answer is to the point, but I would use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html#module-glob) instead.

```
import glob
import random


path = r'C:/Users/katherine/Desktop/testphotos'
chosen_photo = random.choice(glob.glob(path + r'/*.png'))
client.users_setPhoto(image=chosen_photo)
```

I think `glob` is better here because it results in cleaner code (returns absolute path out of the box) and you can also specify the file extension in case you have other stuff in the folders too.

An additional positive side effect is that you can even make it recursive to look inside the folders of the given path as well.